# Get value from a list inside a map elixir

Tags: elixir

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
defmodule WarGame.Core.Game do
 
  defstruct user_cards: [],
        croupier_cards: [],
        user_bets: [],
        bets: [:card_odd, :color_player],
        deck: %{},
        used: [],
        title: nil
```

I would like to create a function that can take a chosen element of a list bets and move it to user_bets. How could I achieve this? There will be only finite (5) elements in this list.

In my head it looks something like this:

```
def select_bet(bet) do
  finds bet in %WarGame.Core.Game{}.bets
  inserts it to %WarGame.Core.Game{}.user_bets
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is immutable, hence your function should receive both a struct and `bet` in the first place. It would return a modified struct if the bet has been found, and an unmodified struct otherwise.

The simplest way would be to check if `-- [bet]` modifies the bets, and if so, add the bet to the `user_bets`.

```elixir
def select_bet(%WarGame.Core.Game{} = game, bet) do
  game_bets = game.bets # for the pin operator to work

  {bets, user_bets} =
    case game_bets -- [bet] do
      ^game_bets -> {game_bets, game.user_bets}
      bets -> {bets, [bet | game.user_bets]}
    end

  %WarGame.Core.Game{game | bets: bets, user_bets: user_bets}
end
```

---

Or, even more concise.

```elixir
def select_bet(%WarGame.Core.Game{} = game, bet) do
  game_bets = game.bets # for the pin operator to work

  case game_bets -- [bet] do
    ^game_bets -> 
      game
    bets ->
      %WarGame.Core.Game{game |
        bets: bets, 
        user_bets: [bet | game.user_bets]}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I try to follow your code I get an error - (CompileError) invalid argument for unary operator ^, expected an existing variable, got: ^game.bets

Comment: Ah, pin operator does not work with directly addressed map fields. I have fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! I am new to Elixir and I would be obligated and thankful if you could explain abit what you did so I could learn it. I don't want to just copy :)

Comment: I did in the answer. I subtract the list consisting of the `bet` only from `bets`. If the list has not changed, there is no such bet available, and we modify nothing. Otherwise, we reassign `bets` to `bets` without `bet` and `user_bets` to `user_bets` plus `bet`.

Comment: And what if I would like to just copy selected element from `bets` to `user_bets`, without moving it?

Comment: I am really grateful for your help. It's  abit complicated for me so it will take some time to understand it completely :)

Comment: Do not modify bets in the second case clause.